# OptimisticLockException JPA

Tags: java, jsf, jpa

I have a problem with a project i am programming.
It is a jsf version 2.1 application. And i use eclipse link as jpa implementation.

The classes i am working on are called User, Logentry, and LoginLogManager. User contains just information about the user of the website and a List of Logentries. Everytime the user logs in a Logentry is created and written into the database. This happens in the LoginLogmanager.

So here is my problem:
When my Logentry table is empty i can create a logentry without no problems and write it in the table, but when i do it another time there is a OptimisticLockException thrown.
I am pretty new to JPA, but till now i found out that this happens when a row that i want to save was updated or deleted since i last read it.
And this really confuses me because i never read the logentry before. This object is created before i write it into the db.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="LOGENTRY")
@NamedQuery(name="Logentry.findAll", query="SELECT l FROM Logentry l")
public class Logentry implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private int LE_ID;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Timestamp CREATE_TIMESTAMP;

    private boolean DELETED;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=1000)
    private String DESCRIPTION;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Timestamp MODIFIEDTS;

    @Version
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private int VERSION_ID;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Logtype
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="LT_ID", nullable=false)
    private Logtype LOGTYPE;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="US_ID", nullable=false)
    private User USER;

    public Logentry() {
    }

    public int getLE_ID() {
        return this.LE_ID;
    }

    public void setLE_ID(int LE_ID) {
        this.LE_ID = LE_ID;
    }

    public Timestamp getCREATE_TIMESTAMP() {
        return this.CREATE_TIMESTAMP;
    }

    public void setCREATE_TIMESTAMP(Timestamp CREATE_TIMESTAMP) {
        this.CREATE_TIMESTAMP = CREATE_TIMESTAMP;
    }

    public boolean getDELETED() {
        return this.DELETED;
    }

    public void setDELETED(boolean DELETED) {
        this.DELETED = DELETED;
    }

    public String getDESCRIPTION() {
        return this.DESCRIPTION;
    }

    public void setDESCRIPTION(String DESCRIPTION) {
        this.DESCRIPTION = DESCRIPTION;
    }

    public Timestamp getMODIFIEDTS() {
        return this.MODIFIEDTS;
    }

    public void setMODIFIEDTS(Timestamp MODIFIEDTS) {
        this.MODIFIEDTS = MODIFIEDTS;
    }

    public int getVERSION_ID() {
        return this.VERSION_ID;
    }

    public void setVERSION_ID(int VERSION_ID) {
        this.VERSION_ID = VERSION_ID;
    }

    public Logtype getLOGTYPE() {
        return this.LOGTYPE;
    }

    public void setLOGTYPE(Logtype LOGTYPE) {
        this.LOGTYPE = LOGTYPE;
    }

    public User getUSER() {
        return this.USER;
    }

    public void setUSER(User USER) {
        this.USER = USER;
    }

}`
```

my user Pojo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
@NamedQuery(name="User.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM User u")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(User.class.getName());

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private int US_ID;

    private Timestamp BIRTHDAY;

    @Column(length=50)
    private String CITY;

    @Column(length=50)
    private String COUNTRY;

    @Column(length=20)
    private String DEGREE;

    private boolean DELETED;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=75)
    private String EMAIL;

    @Column(length=45)
    private String FAX;

    @Column(length=100)
    private String FIRST_NAME;

    @Column(length=45)
    private String FIXED_LINE;

    private Timestamp INACTIVATION_TIMESTAMP;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=100)
    private String LAST_NAME;

    @Column(length=45)
    private String MOBILE_PHONE;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Timestamp MODIFIEDTS;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=50)
    private String PASSWORD;

    @Column(length=50)
    private String STATE;

    @Column(length=100)
    private String STREET_NAME;

    @Column(length=20)
    private String STREET_NO;

    @Column(length=20)
    private String TITLE;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=75)
    private String USER_NAME;

    @Version
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private int VERSION_ID;

    @Column(length=10)
    private String ZIP;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Logentry
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="USER")
    private List<Logentry> LOGENTRIES;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to SupplierUserRole
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="USER")
    private List<Supplier_User_Role> SUPPLIER_USER_ROLES;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Taskbox
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="FROM_USER")
    private List<Taskbox> TASKBOX_AS_USERS;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Taskbox
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="TO_USER")
    private List<Taskbox> TASKBOX_AS_TOS;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Language
    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="LA_ID", nullable=false)
    private Language LANGUAGE;

    public User() {
    }

    public int getUS_ID() {
        return this.US_ID;
    }

    public void setUS_ID(int US_ID) {
        this.US_ID = US_ID;
    }

    public Timestamp getBIRTHDAY() {
        return this.BIRTHDAY;
    }

    public void setBIRTHDAY(Timestamp BIRTHDAY) {
        this.BIRTHDAY = BIRTHDAY;
    }

    public String getCITY() {
        return this.CITY;
    }

    public void setCITY(String CITY) {
        this.CITY = CITY;
    }

    public String getCOUNTRY() {
        return this.COUNTRY;
    }

    public void setCOUNTRY(String COUNTRY) {
        this.COUNTRY = COUNTRY;
    }

    public String getDEGREE() {
        return this.DEGREE;
    }

    public void setDEGREE(String DEGREE) {
        this.DEGREE = DEGREE;
    }

    public boolean getDELETED() {
        return this.DELETED;
    }

    public void setDELETED(boolean DELETED) {
        this.DELETED = DELETED;
    }

    public String getEMAIL() {
        return this.EMAIL;
    }

    public void setEMAIL(String EMAIL) {
        this.EMAIL = EMAIL;
    }

    public String getFAX() {
        return this.FAX;
    }

    public void setFAX(String FAX) {
        this.FAX = FAX;
    }

    public String getFIRST_NAME() {
        return this.FIRST_NAME;
    }

    public void setFIRST_NAME(String FIRST_NAME) {
        this.FIRST_NAME = FIRST_NAME;
    }

    public String getFIXED_LINE() {
        return this.FIXED_LINE;
    }

    public void setFIXED_LINE(String FIXED_LINE) {
        this.FIXED_LINE = FIXED_LINE;
    }

    public Timestamp getINACTIVATION_TIMESTAMP() {
        return this.INACTIVATION_TIMESTAMP;
    }

    public void setINACTIVATION_TIMESTAMP(Timestamp INACTIVATION_TIMESTAMP) {
        this.INACTIVATION_TIMESTAMP = INACTIVATION_TIMESTAMP;
    }

    public String getLAST_NAME() {
        return this.LAST_NAME;
    }

    public void setLAST_NAME(String LAST_NAME) {
        this.LAST_NAME = LAST_NAME;
    }

    public String getMOBILE_PHONE() {
        return this.MOBILE_PHONE;
    }

    public void setMOBILE_PHONE(String MOBILE_PHONE) {
        this.MOBILE_PHONE = MOBILE_PHONE;
    }

    public Timestamp getMODIFIEDTS() {
        return this.MODIFIEDTS;
    }

    public void setMODIFIEDTS(Timestamp MODIFIEDTS) {
        this.MODIFIEDTS = MODIFIEDTS;
    }

    public String getPASSWORD() {
        return this.PASSWORD;
    }

    public void setPASSWORD(String PASSWORD) {
        this.PASSWORD = PASSWORD;
    }

    public String getSTATE() {
        return this.STATE;
    }

    public void setSTATE(String STATE) {
        this.STATE = STATE;
    }

    public String getSTREET_NAME() {
        return this.STREET_NAME;
    }

    public void setSTREET_NAME(String STREET_NAME) {
        this.STREET_NAME = STREET_NAME;
    }

    public String getSTREET_NO() {
        return this.STREET_NO;
    }

    public void setSTREET_NO(String STREET_NO) {
        this.STREET_NO = STREET_NO;
    }

    public String getTITLE() {
        return this.TITLE;
    }

    public void setTITLE(String TITLE) {
        this.TITLE = TITLE;
    }

    public String getUSER_NAME() {
        return this.USER_NAME;
    }

    public void setUSER_NAME(String USER_NAME) {
        this.USER_NAME = USER_NAME;
    }

    public int getVERSION_ID() {
        return this.VERSION_ID;
    }

    public void setVERSION_ID(int VERSION_ID) {
        this.VERSION_ID = VERSION_ID;
    }

    public String getZIP() {
        return this.ZIP;
    }

    public void setZIP(String ZIP) {
        this.ZIP = ZIP;
    }

    public List<Logentry> getLOGENTRIES() {
        return this.LOGENTRIES;
    }

    public void setLOGENTRIES(List<Logentry> LOGENTRIES) {
        this.LOGENTRIES = LOGENTRIES;
    }

    public Logentry addLOGENTRy(Logentry LOGENTRy) {
        getLOGENTRIES().add(LOGENTRy);

        if(this.getLOGENTRIES()!=null)
        log.info("Liste mit Logs ist nicht null!");

        LOGENTRy.setUSER(this);

        return LOGENTRy;
    }

    public Logentry removeLOGENTRy(Logentry LOGENTRy) {
        getLOGENTRIES().remove(LOGENTRy);
        LOGENTRy.setUSER(null);

        return LOGENTRy;
    }

    public List<Supplier_User_Role> getSUPPLIER_USER_ROLES() {
        return this.SUPPLIER_USER_ROLES;
    }

    public void setSUPPLIER_USER_ROLES(List<Supplier_User_Role> SUPPLIER_USER_ROLES) {
        this.SUPPLIER_USER_ROLES = SUPPLIER_USER_ROLES;
    }

    public Supplier_User_Role addSUPPLIER_USER_ROLE(Supplier_User_Role SUPPLIER_USER_ROLE) {
        getSUPPLIER_USER_ROLES().add(SUPPLIER_USER_ROLE);
        SUPPLIER_USER_ROLE.setUSER(this);

        return SUPPLIER_USER_ROLE;
    }

    public Supplier_User_Role removeSUPPLIER_USER_ROLE(Supplier_User_Role SUPPLIER_USER_ROLE) {
        getSUPPLIER_USER_ROLES().remove(SUPPLIER_USER_ROLE);
        SUPPLIER_USER_ROLE.setUSER(null);

        return SUPPLIER_USER_ROLE;
    }

    public List<Taskbox> getTASKBOX_AS_USERS() {
        return this.TASKBOX_AS_USERS;
    }

    public void setTASKBOX_AS_USERS(List<Taskbox> TASKBOX_AS_USERS) {
        this.TASKBOX_AS_USERS = TASKBOX_AS_USERS;
    }

    public Taskbox addTASKBOX_AS_USER(Taskbox TASKBOX_AS_USER) {
        getTASKBOX_AS_USERS().add(TASKBOX_AS_USER);
        TASKBOX_AS_USER.setFROM_USER(this);

        return TASKBOX_AS_USER;
    }

    public Taskbox removeTASKBOX_AS_USER(Taskbox TASKBOX_AS_USER) {
        getTASKBOX_AS_USERS().remove(TASKBOX_AS_USER);
        TASKBOX_AS_USER.setFROM_USER(null);

        return TASKBOX_AS_USER;
    }

    public List<Taskbox> getTASKBOX_AS_TOS() {
        return this.TASKBOX_AS_TOS;
    }

    public void setTASKBOX_AS_TOS(List<Taskbox> TASKBOX_AS_TOS) {
        this.TASKBOX_AS_TOS = TASKBOX_AS_TOS;
    }

    public Taskbox addTASKBOX_AS_TO(Taskbox TASKBOX_AS_TO) {
        getTASKBOX_AS_TOS().add(TASKBOX_AS_TO);
        TASKBOX_AS_TO.setTO_USER(this);

        return TASKBOX_AS_TO;
    }

    public Taskbox removeTASKBOX_AS_TO(Taskbox TASKBOX_AS_TO) {
        getTASKBOX_AS_TOS().remove(TASKBOX_AS_TO);
        TASKBOX_AS_TO.setTO_USER(null);

        return TASKBOX_AS_TO;
    }

    public Language getLANGUAGE() {
        return this.LANGUAGE;
    }

    public void setLANGUAGE(Language LANGUAGE) {
        this.LANGUAGE = LANGUAGE;
    }

}
```

and my LoginLogManager:

```
@ManagedBean(name="loginLogManager")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginLogManager implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoginLogManager.class.getName());

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{logtypeDaoImpl}")
    private LogtypeDao logTypeDao;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{logentryDaoImpl}")
    private LogentryDao logEntryDao;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{userDaoImpl}")
    private UserDao userDao;

    private Timestamp timeStamp;            
    private Logentry logEntry;
    private Logtype logtype;


    public void createLog(String description,int logTypeId,User user){

        timeStamp=new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        logtype=logTypeDao.findByID(logTypeId);


        logEntry=new Logentry();
        logEntry.setCREATE_TIMESTAMP(timeStamp);
        logEntry.setDESCRIPTION(description);
        logEntry.setLOGTYPE(logtype);
        logEntry.setMODIFIEDTS(timeStamp);


        user.addLOGENTRy(logEntry);
        userDao.update(user);

    }


    public static Logger getLog() {
        return log;
    }


    public static void setLog(Logger log) {
        LoginLogManager.log = log;
    }


    public LogtypeDao getLogTypeDao() {
        return logTypeDao;
    }


    public void setLogTypeDao(LogtypeDao logTypeDao) {
        this.logTypeDao = logTypeDao;
    }


    public UserDao getUserDao() {
        return userDao;
    }


    public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }


    public Timestamp getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }


    public void setTimeStamp(Timestamp timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }


    public Logentry getLogEntry() {
        return logEntry;
    }


    public void setLogEntry(Logentry logEntry) {
        this.logEntry = logEntry;
    }


    public Logtype getLogtype() {
        return logtype;
    }


    public void setLogtype(Logtype logtype) {
        this.logtype = logtype;
    }


    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }


    public LogentryDao getLogEntryDao() {
        return logEntryDao;
    }


    public void setLogEntryDao(LogentryDao logEntryDao) {
        this.logEntryDao = logEntryDao;
    }



}
```

Here is my UserDao:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "userDaoImpl")
@SessionScoped
public class UserDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<User> implements UserDao,
        Serializable {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UserDaoImpl.class.getName());

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5280393555113818663L;

    /**
     * Loads a User by his Username
     * 
     * @param username
     * @return founded User
     */
    @Override
    public User findUserByUserName(String username) {
        em = EMF.getEMF().createEntityManager();
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);
        Root<User> user = cq.from(User.class);
        cq.where(cb.and(cb.equal(user.get(User_.USER_NAME), username)));

        // EntityType<User>user_=entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(User.class);

        TypedQuery<User> typedQuery = em.createQuery(cq);
        List<User> userList = typedQuery.getResultList();
        em.close();
        return userList.get(0);
    }

    /**
     * Loads a User by his Username and Password
     * 
     * @param username
     * @param password
     * @return founded User
     */
    @Override
    public User findUserByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password) {
        em = EMF.getEMF().createEntityManager();
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);
        Root<User> user = cq.from(User.class);
        cq.where(cb.and(cb.equal(user.get(User_.USER_NAME), username),
                cb.equal(user.get(User_.PASSWORD), password)));

        log.info(""+username + " "+password);
        log.info(""+user.get(User_.USER_NAME)+ " "+(user.get(User_.PASSWORD)));

        // EntityType<User>user_=entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(User.class);

        TypedQuery<User> typedQuery = em.createQuery(cq);
        List<User> userList = typedQuery.getResultList();
        em.close();
        return userList.get(0);
    }
}
```

and the implemented GenericDAO:

```
public abstract class GenericDaoImpl<T> implements GenericDao<T> {

    protected EntityManager em = null;

    private Class<T> type;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public GenericDaoImpl() {
        Type t = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;
        type = (Class<T>) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    /**
     * Inserts a new row to the database
     * 
     *
     * @param t
     *            : Object to insert
     * @return Object with key and new version
     */
    @Override
    public T insert(final T t) {
        em = EMF.getEMF().createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(t);
        // em.flush();
        // em.refresh(t);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        return t;
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a row in the database by id
     * 
     *
     * @param id
     *            : id of the Object
     */
    @Override
    public void delete(final Object id) {
        em = EMF.getEMF().createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.remove(em.getReference(type, id));
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }

    /**
     * Finds a row in the database by id and return it
     * 
     * 
     * @param id
     *            : id of the Object
     * @return Object, which is found
     */
    @Override
    public T findByID(final Object id) {
        em = EMF.getEMF().createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        T te = (T) em.find(type, id);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        return te;
    }

    /**
     * Updates a row in the database
     * 
     * 
     * @param t
     *            : Object to update
     * @return Object with new version
     */
    @Override
    public T update(final T t) {
        em = EMF.getEMF().createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        T te = em.merge(t);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        return te;
    }

    /**
     * Counts the number of rows in this database table
     * 
     *
     * @param params
     *            : database arguments for counting
     * @return number of rows
     */
    @Override
    public long countAll(final Map<String, Object> params) {

        final StringBuffer queryString = new StringBuffer(
                "SELECT count(o) from ");

        queryString.append(type.getSimpleName()).append(" o ");
        queryString.append(getQueryClauses(params, null));

        em = EMF.getEMF().createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        final Query query = em.createQuery(queryString.toString());
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();

        return (Long) query.getSingleResult();

    }

    /**
     * Finds All Objects in this database table
     * 
     * 
     * @return all Objects in the database table
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> findAll() {
        em = EMF.getEMF().createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        List<T> teList = em.createQuery(
                "Select t from " + type.getSimpleName() + " t").getResultList();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        return teList;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a part of a String for a Query
     * 
     * @return created String
     */
    private String getQueryClauses(final Map<String, Object> params,
            final Map<String, Object> orderParams) {
        final StringBuffer queryString = new StringBuffer();
        if ((params != null) && !params.isEmpty()) {
            queryString.append(" where ");
            for (final Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> it = params
                    .entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                final Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = it.next();
                if (entry.getValue() instanceof Boolean) {
                    queryString.append(entry.getKey()).append(" is ")
                            .append(entry.getValue()).append(" ");
                } else {
                    if (entry.getValue() instanceof Number) {
                        queryString.append(entry.getKey()).append(" = ")
                                .append(entry.getValue());
                    } else {
                        // string equality
                        queryString.append(entry.getKey()).append(" = '")
                                .append(entry.getValue()).append("'");
                    }
                }
                if (it.hasNext()) {
                    queryString.append(" and ");
                }
            }
        }
        if ((orderParams != null) && !orderParams.isEmpty()) {
            queryString.append(" order by ");
            for (final Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> it = orderParams
                    .entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                final Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = it.next();
                queryString.append(entry.getKey()).append(" ");
                if (entry.getValue() != null) {
                    queryString.append(entry.getValue());
                }
                if (it.hasNext()) {
                    queryString.append(", ");
                }
            }
        }
        return queryString.toString();
    }
}
```

As i said before when i log in a second time and there is already a log in the db it throws the OLE.

**The object [at.dccs.csm.database.entity.Logentry@419a7187] cannot be merged because it has changed or been deleted since it was last read.**

Thats the exception description.
I have no idea why this Exception is thrown here.
I hope you can give me advice and help me with my problem.

Comment: Can you show the code for UserDao?

Comment: When you are using `IDENTITY` strategy for id generation, it is recommended to implement equals and hashCode(Also, `addLogEntry()` method may throw NullPointer). That might causing the problem. In general, `Optimiatic` behavior is because of your `@Version` field. Try implement both methods and see.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply!  
i will try to implement these mehtods now.  

And i added the userDao and the genericDao that is implemented to the 
question above.

Comment: W implemented a tostring() and hashcode() now, but there is still the OptimisticLockException thrown.

Answer (score 0):

First, in Java Word, uppercase attribute is for static final field. You can search for JavaBeans spec.

```
private Long id; public Long getId(){return id;} public void setId(Long id){this.id=id;}
```

I suggest you to use the primitive wrapper instead of primitive for the id. I mean, use Integer instead of int. If the id is null, then your entity is not persisted.

Second, you don't need to override equals / hashcode to make it work.

Third, in JPA world, you don't need any DAO. You can search for Domain Store pattern. The entity manager already do the job "CRUD".

When you close the entity manager, all entities are detached from the persistence context. So, each call to your DAO have a different context cause you create a different entity / transaction.

In your DAO world, you must not open and close the entity manager and create a transaction inside the dao. You want to do multiple requests before commiting a transaction. If you create multiple transaction, just the last part will rollback if an error happened. That's very bad.

You need to have a service layer to do that job.

For your problem, in the same transaction, merge your user, merge your log entry (set the user) and then add the log entry in your user.